# Consent screen instead Email picker

Tags: android, authentication, google-plus, google-plus-signin

With this code i get the something like the first Image to pick the related account.. i want the  default pick de google plus account and appears something like the second image the consent screen.

```
private synchronized GoogleApiClient buildGoogleApiClient() {
    GoogleApiClient.Builder builder = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API, Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build())
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN);

    return builder.build();
}

 private void resolveSignInError(ConnectionResult result) {
    if (mSignInIntent != null) {
        try {
            mSignInProgress = STATE_IN_PROGRESS;
            startIntentSenderForResult(mSignInIntent.getIntentSender(), RC_SIGN_IN, null, 0, 0, 0);

        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Sign in intent could not be sent: "
                    + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            mSignInProgress = STATE_SIGN_IN;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    } else {
        createErrorDialog().show();
    }
}
```

Instead this.

[image]

I want something like this.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried following [this guide](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in)?

Comment: Yeah i did.. Same issue.